# Compile Error: Field is not writeable: Report.Name

Tags: reporting

I am getting error 'Compile Error: Field is not writeable: Report.Name' while checking the name field of report.
Does any one have any idea!
Code is like:

> list lstreports=[select id,name from Report];
>    for(Report report : lstreports)
>    {
>       if(report.name='Report_SimMapPoint_for_Account')
>       {
>           SimMapPointForAccount=report.id;
>       }
>    }

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta change the if statement condition so that instead of the assignment operator you need to add the equality operator:

Change the if condition to :

```
if(report.name=='Report_SimMapPoint_for_Account') {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(report.name='Report_SimMapPoint_for_Account')
```

to

```
if(report.name=='Report_SimMapPoint_for_Account')
```

Comment: What a silly mistake I did..! Thanks for helping me.